# Show form when div is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am generating a list of entries from a JSON feed. I want to click a div and bring up the edit modal. I'm having some issues getting the relatedTarget from the `click` event. It's returned as undefined.

Is there another way of passing data to the modal?

```
$.getJSON('api/v1/module', function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, learning) {
        var $div = $('<div>')
        .append(
            $('<p>').text(learning.title),
            $('<p>').text(learning.lastupdated)
        )
        .addClass('panel panel-default')
        .attr('data-title', learning.title)
        .appendTo('.module-list')
        .on('click', function(){
            $('#edit-module').modal({
                show: true
            })
        })
    });
})

$('#edit-module').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
    var recipient = button.data('title') // Extract info from data-* attributes
      // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
      // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)

    console.log( event.relatedTarget )
    console.log( event )
    console.log( button )
    console.log( JSON.stringify(button) )
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Boostrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events):

> If caused by a click, the clicked element is available as the
>   relatedTarget property of the event.

But here the display is caused by `modal()`, not the initial click.

To have the click trigger the display as described in the docs, you need to call the modal using Boostrap's `data-toggle`.  Add those data attributes, and remove your `.on()` handler:

```
$.getJSON('api/v1/module', function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, learning) {
        var $div = $('<div>')
        ...
        .attr('data-title', learning.title)
        .attr("data-toggle", "modal")
        .attr("data-target", "#edit-module")
        .appendTo('.module-list')
    });
})
```

Comment: Combing this with hooking into the modal's show event sorted it. Thanks. While i got you. Are there better ways to store JSON data/id on div's and such? I find it hard to store relation data for further use.

Comment: Glad it helped.  You can store data in data attributes, or read it from the actual content you are creating.  Eg `var id=button.attr('id'), title = $('p.title', button).text();`.  You could also maybe write it out separately as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation for your dynamically-created `.panel` elements.

> **Direct and delegated events**: http://api.jquery.com/on/
>
> **Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist at the time your code makes the call to** `.on()`. To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, place scripts after the elements in the HTML markup or perform event binding inside a document ready handler. Alternatively, use delegated events to attach event handlers.

```
$(function() {
  $('.module-list').on('click', '.panel', function(){
    $('#edit-module').modal({
      show: true
    })
  })
});

$.getJSON('api/v1/module', function(data){
    $.each(data, function(i, learning) {
        var $div = $('<div>')
        .append(
            $('<p>').text(learning.title),
            $('<p>').text(learning.lastupdated)
        )
        .addClass('panel panel-default')
        .attr('data-title', learning.title)
        .appendTo('.module-list')
    });
})

$('#edit-module').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
    var recipient = button.data('title') // Extract info from data-* attributes
      // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
      // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
    var modal = $(this)
    modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)

    console.log( event.relatedTarget )
    console.log( event )
    console.log( button )
    console.log( JSON.stringify(button) )
})
```

Comment: The event handlers are added to the elements at the time they are created, not before, that is not the problem here.